# Registering a VB6 Interop DLL with Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, castle-windsor

I'm converting a C# solution to use Castle.Windsor. One of the dependencies of some of my components is a VB6 developed DLL which is referenced currently via Interop.

How can I register this with Castle.Windsor successfully?

Before:

```
private AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl _suspControl;
_suspControl = new AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl();
```

This works just fine. However, if I register like this:

```
container.Register(Component
                   .For<AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl>()
                   .ImplementedBy<AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl>());
```

The services count is incremented by one, and the debug suggests it's fully resolved. However when I next register a component which depends on this, the debug suggests it cannot be resolved.

**Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
'AeroSusp.VB6.SuspControl' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl' which was not registered.**

And indeed once I try and use the component:

Can't create component 'AeroSusp.VB6.SuspControl' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

**'AeroSusp.VB6.SuspControl' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'AeroSuspCalc.SuspControl' which was not registered.**

Googling this hasn't helped much!

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem ? I think it's because the interop types are included in the managed dll so if you've 2 dll you end with 2 interop types for the same control. Registering one type doesn't allow you to resolve using the second type. But I still search a solution for this..

Comment: No I've not resolved it. Your idea sounds plausible though.